# Replacing Substrings with Incremental Characters

Tags: java

I'm trying to replace certain substrings with a character while incrementing. For example,

```
Input:  Hello World
Output: He...o Wor...d
```

Everytime a character is found it will increment the amount of characters to be outputted, I'm also supposed to do this without any arrays or arraylists.

I'm stuck with how to tackle this problem, I realize I'll need a variable to count the amount of times the substring is found, but as for replacing it I don't know what to do.

Also, I would prefer not being given the code, I'd rather do it myself.

EDIT: The substring doesn't have to be one character necessarily, it can be multiple characters. ie. "He", "llo", etc.

Comment: Can you use replaceAll and regular expressions?

Comment: Then it could be something like `output = input.replaceAll("l+", "...");` - to replave each l by ... or if the first l is . and the 2nd .. etc you could use `input.replaceFirst("l", points);` in a loop where points does `points += ".";` at each iteration

Comment: I tried the replaceFirst, however my IDE is giving me a warning that replaceFirst is being ignored.

Comment: You need to store the result... `temp =input;` before the loop then `temp = temp.replaceFirst(...);` inside the loop.

Comment: Perfect! I got it to work, if you want to repost a summary of what you said as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Sleep time here - maybe tomorrow. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at StringBuffer. You can use it to setCharAt a given index and insert a String at a given index. You can then get this done with nested loops. The outside loop while loop searches for the string you need to replace.
Use `while (buffer.indexOf (target) >=0)`
 The inside e loop inserts `counter` number of '.'

Comment: Sorry I didn't say this in the OP, I'll edit it in a minute. But the substring that needs to be replaced can be more than one character, "l", "ld", "He", etc.

So I don't think that I'd be able to use charAt, or setCharAt.

Answer (score 0):

Use a variable to count the number of times a substring occurs (as you said). Use that variable as a counter for a loop to determine how many replacement characters to print.

```
count = numberOfSubString()

for 0 to count
  replaceChar()
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you use something like `StringBuilder`? You can iterate through each character of the input String, and if it does not need to be replaced, `append` it to the `StringBuilder`. If it does need to be replaced, `append` the special character however many times you need to, (based on your counter you mentioned). Then at the end, convert your `StringBuilder` to a `String` (using `.toString`) and return that.

Comment: I tried to do something like this, however the characters that I need to replace are stored as a String as they can be any combination of characters.

I may not be clear with that but what I mean is it can be "l", "ld", etc. that needs to be replaced.

Comment: Well then I would probably suggest doing something like @assylias suggested and use a regular expression and the `replaceAll()` method.